# asp.net OAuth token error 401: unauthorized

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, access-token, unauthorized

I'm working with ASP.NET Web API (C#). I try to implement token based authentication. Here is my Startup.Auth class

```
    public static Startup()
    {
        PublicClientId = "self";

        UserManagerFactory = () => new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>());

        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),

            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };

     }

    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

    public static Func<UserManager<ApplicationUser>> UserManagerFactory { get; set; }

    public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
    /* login with third party login providers......*/
    }
```

I also have another method for issuing tokens

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
    /* some stuff here...*/
    if (hasRegistered)
            {
                identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
                IEnumerable<Claim> claims = externalLogin.GetClaims();
                identity.AddClaims(claims);
                Authentication.SignIn(identity);
            }

        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, new AuthenticationProperties());
        var currentUtc = new Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.SystemClock().UtcNow;
        ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = currentUtc;
        ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = currentUtc.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(2));
        var accessToken = Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);


        // Create the response building a JSON object that mimics exactly the one issued by the default /Token endpoint
        JObject token = new JObject(
            new JProperty("userName", user.UserName),
            new JProperty("id", user.Id),
            new JProperty("access_token", accessToken),
            new JProperty("token_type", "bearer"),
            new JProperty("expires_in", TimeSpan.FromHours(2).TotalSeconds.ToString()),
            new JProperty(".issued", currentUtc.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'")),
            new JProperty(".expires", currentUtc.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(2)).ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'"))
        );
        return Ok(token);
    }
```

Both methods work. But if I put [Authorize] in controller and use Tokens issued using second method (Login) I always get "Authorization has been denied for this request" error. Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are successfully getting the token back after authentication. To access the resource (apicontroller with authorize attribute) you will need to will pass the bearer token (prefixed with 'Bearer ') in the Authorization header. Example: 'Bearer [Tokenstring]'.

You can test this by downloading a restclient(rest console, postman, etc.) tool on your preferred browser. try a normal GET request and place 'Bearer [token]' in the authorization header field. I hope this helps.